# Reliable multiplication and modulo with numbers larger than maxint

Tags: algorithm, performance, modular-arithmetic

**Situation**
After working on a [coding kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/become-immortal/javascript) I finally got the algorithm to work on my small test cases.
Only to find out it did not work on a large scale, the time is not an issue but the size of the numbers are.
In one of my calculations in one of the test cases I need to perform the following calculation.

```
var numberOfColumns = 34359738368;
var numberOfRows = 28827050410;
var valueOverflow = 13719506;
var totalOfSingleRow = (numberOfColumns * (numberOfColumns - 1))/2;
var totalGridValue = totalOfSingleRow * numberOfRows;
var result = (totalOfSingleRow * totalGridValue) % valueOverflow;
```

Because the top row is sequential, I can calculate the sum of the first row by doing `(numberOfColumns * (numberOfColumns - 1))/2;`.
Then I need to multiply that answer by the number of rows and apply the modulo to get my resulting value.

**The problem**
The problem is that Javascript can only calculate reliable with number less than `9007199254740991`.
Only the calculation above results in a `totalGridValue` of `17016487081526963049249353236480`.
You can imagine that my calculation does not result in the desired value of `10552574` because the value gets truncated to 1.7016487081526963e+31.
This results in the wrong value of `8479672`

**Question**
How can I alter my calculation so the result becomes the desired `10552574`.
I've tried applying the modulo operator sooner on the `numberOfColumns` without the desired result.
I've also looked at adding two large values as string but this process would become to slow as I have to add two strings to many times.

**Note**
Because I need to submit this on codewars, I cannot use any external libraries!
I can use other languages though, but I know it is possible in javascript.

Comment: Well, an important trick : `(A*B)%M = ((A%M)*(B%M))%M`.

Comment: That's certainly a very useful trick. However, this is not trivial to apply to a quantity such as (c * (c-1) / 2) % n. If you apply that for c=2 and n=2 you certainly get the wrong result (0 instead of 1), and c=13 and n=8 (2 instead of 6) is another of the many failure cases.

Comment: @rwp it does work if you calculate the division by 2 first so the correct formula would be `c % n * ((c-1) / 2 % n) % n`. Provided that c-1 is an even number, if c-1 is an uneven number the formula is `(c-1) % n * (c / 2 % n) % n`

Comment: @RickHoving - Good point, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were on the right track with moving the modulus operation further up the chain, but I wouldn't use the modulo operator for that.  Instead, use regular floating point division, and carry that value through to the last step, when all other calculations are done, then convert that float's decimal part into an integer.  Basically, with pure division, you're just doing a transformation on the value, rather than changing the value.  Once you go to the modulus, you've changed the value.   (I'd also change the totalSingleRow formula to divide the big values then multiply the results, rather than multiply then divide.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree that moving the modulus operation further up the chain is the correct basic idea. The one subtlety is handling the calculation of totalOfSingleRow, because it involves a division by two. I think what you need to do is perform that stage modulo (2 * valueOverflow), and only compute the result modulo valueOverflow at the end. Perhaps as follows:

```
var doubleOverflow = 2 * valueOverflow;
var totalOfSingleRow = (((numberOfColumns % doubleOverflow) * (numberOfColumns + doubleOverflow - 1)) / 2) % valueOverflow;
var totalGridValue = (totalOfSingleRow * (numberOfRows % valueOverflow)) % valueOverflow;
var result = (totalOfSingleRow * totalGridValue) % valueOverflow;
```

You'll need to check that (4 * valueOverflow*valueOverflow) is less than the maximum integer value that can be represented correctly.